# turn switchery checkbox to uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use [switchery checkbox](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) now, how can I uncheck or checked it using jquery if I click a button, like

```
$("button").click(function(){
    //uncheck switchery
});
```

Comment: clickCheckbox.checked - Checking state in above mentioned link.

Comment: what is that clinkCheckbox?

Comment: checkbox property "checked" to used. see my answer.

Comment: @AmitG: i want to turn the switchery to active state/checked not check its status. what im gonna to that false and true pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "checked" property.
Edit:
I am explicitly triggering switchry change.

Reference code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/switchery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/switchery.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked /></p>
<p><input type="button" class="js-button" value="get status"></p>
<p><input type="button" class="toggle-button" value="toggle"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('.js-switch');
    var switchry = new Switchery(checkbox, { size: 'small' });
    $('.js-button').click(function (){
        alert(checkbox.checked);
    });
    $('.toggle-button').click(function (){
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
        switchry.handleOnchange(checkbox.checked);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i mean make it checked/active state not checking its state

Comment: can you explain those syntax above please?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything but only one solution is possible.

```
$('.switcher').prop('checked', true);
```

OR

```
$('.switcher').prop('checked', false);
```